# Show that if the sequence $(y_n)$ converges to $y$, then $(1/y_n)$ converges to $1/y$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

> Given $(y_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers that converge to $y$ and all terms are not $0$. Show that the sequence $(1/y_n)$ converge to $1/y$.

I was trying to prove that the sequence $(x_n/y_n)$ converge to $x/y$, which I have to show that $(1/y_n)$ converge to $1/y$. Do anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What is $(x_n)$?

Comment: $y\neq 0$ seems necessary.

Comment: If $y_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and $y = 0$ then the statement is false.

Comment: It is not necessary that all the terms are non-zero, it is enough that the terms are not zero for n sufficiently large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use that $$\left|\dfrac{1}{y_n}-\dfrac{1}{y}\right|=\dfrac{|y_n-y|}{|y_ny|}$$ 
and that $y_n$ is bounded away from $0$ (meaning $|y_n|>r$ for some $r>0$ and $n\in\mathbb N$).

As noted in the comments by  *girianshiido* and *TMM*, we must have the extra hypothesis that $y\neq0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Assuming $y\neq 0$ we have
$$
\frac1{y_n}-\frac1y=(y-y_n)\frac1y\frac1y_n.
$$
Now you just have to show that $\left(\frac1{y_n}\right)$ is bounded for $n$ large enough.